# Solving for the missing real and imaginary parts that satisfy the following equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve for the real and imaginary parts of the equation:
$(3+xi)(y+3i)=-6+17i$ Can I just isolate each individual part and set it equal to its respective part?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

If $z = a + bi$ and $w = c + di$ are complex numbers then $z = w$ if and only if $a = c$ and $b = d$. That is, if and only if their real and imaginary parts coincide.

Comment: $3+y=-6$ and $xi+3i = 17i$ therefore $R[-3]$ and $Im[14]$. Is this is a valid statement?

Comment: No, you first need to rewrite the left hand side as a complex number of the form $a + bi$. This means you need to multiply it out using the distributive property. $\textit{Then}$ you can equate the real parts and the imaginary parts from each side.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I understand now.